# how to extract a value from a string in xml using grep or awk in Linux

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have a file containing:

```
DEVICE="7" PGMNR="24" VCONF="800"
```

In this file, I want to find `PGMNR="24"` and I need the value 24 without the `"`.

The `PGMNR="24"` may be located anywhere in the line.
The beginning, middle or in the end of the line.

I can't figure out how to get the value.

XML Sample from comments:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NT3Config>
  <System
      Dev="7"
      PGMNR="24"
      VCONF="800 800"
  />
  <WA-NT
      info="23 1 1 1 61 17 00"
      name="Soja T#1"
  />
  <WA-NT
      info="23 2 2 1 61 17 00"
      name="MatadorM"
  />
  <SCALE
      AdNr="0"
      Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0"
      Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
  />
  <SCALE
      AdNr="1"
      Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0"
      Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
  />
  <SCALE
      AdNr="2"
      Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0"
      Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
  />
  <GSM
      PIN=""
      PORT="0"
      TLF=""
  />
</NT3Config>
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more of your sample XML? Because the answer is 'don't use awk or grep' because XML doesn't work that way.

Comment: I would use awk to find the line containing PGMNR=" and then extract the value somehow. But I cant figure out how.

Comment: Complete file: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NT3Config>
<System Dev="7" PGMNR="24" VCONF="800 800" />
<WA-NT name="Soja T#1" info="23 1 1 1 61 17 00" />
<WA-NT name="MatadorM" info="23 2 2 1 61 17 00" />
<SCALE AdNr="0" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" />
<SCALE AdNr="1" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" />
<SCALE AdNr="2" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" />
<GSM TLF="" PIN="" PORT="0" />

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [edit] your question to add extra information. It is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments. Also, comments can be deleted with no warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already answered this using a parser - what I consider the 'right way'.

This would be the "wrong way" but should do the trick with the very minimum amount of POSIX tools:

```
grep PGMNR $filename | sed -e 's/.*PGMNR=\"//' -e 's/\".*//'
```

Comment: YES IT WORKS. I have used many hours to try to solve this. Thank you very much. Regards Søren.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` with PCRE (`-P`) :

```
grep -Po 'PGMNR=\"\K[^"]+(?=\")' file.txt
```

- `PGMNR=\"` will match the `PGMNR="` portion, `\K` will discard the match
- `[^"]+` will contain the number
- The zero width positive lookahead pattern `(?=\")` will make sure that the number is followed by a `"`.

Comment: My grep does not accept the -P

Comment: >grep -Po 'PGMNR=\"\K[^"]+(?=\")' conf.xml
grep: invalid option -- 'P'
BusyBox v1.19.3 (2012-09-20 14:45:49 CEST) multi-call binary.

Usage: grep [-HhnlLoqvsriwFE] [-m N] [-A/B/C N] PATTERN/-e PATTERN.../-f FILE [FILE]...

Comment: Hi heemayl, thanks for your fast reply, do you have a workaround?

Comment: @SørenBonefeld busybox comes with very minimal set of options..sorry it won't work using `grep` unless you have a PCRE parsing option..

Comment: busybox constraint is worth specifying in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Please - don't. XML doesn't work well with regular expressions and line based parsing, because there's a bunch of things you can do in XML that are semantically identical but with different 'pattern matches'.

With `xmlstarlet` you can extract an `xpath` expression which will give you your value.

Or my favourite is using perl and `XML::Twig` to parse your XML, and again - get the value you want that way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' ) ->  parse ( \*DATA );
print "PGMNR: ", $twig -> get_xpath('//System',0) -> att('PGMNR'),"\n";

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NT3Config>
<System Dev="7" PGMNR="24" VCONF="800 800" /> 
<WA-NT name="Soja T#1" info="23 1 1 1 61 17 00" />
<WA-NT name="MatadorM" info="23 2 2 1 61 17 00" />
<SCALE AdNr="0" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" />
<SCALE AdNr="1" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" />
<SCALE AdNr="2" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" />
<GSM TLF="" PIN="" PORT="0" />
</NT3Config>
```

This can 'one liner' if it's needed, or you can `xmlstarlet` that XPATH.

```
perl -0777 -MXML::Twig -e 'print XML::Twig -> parse ( <> )-> get_xpath('//System',0) -> att('PGMNR');'
```

Note - the reason why I'm vehemently against regular expression based parsing is because these are all  completely valid ways of presenting your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NT3Config>
  <System
      Dev="7"
      PGMNR="24"
      VCONF="800 800"
  />
  <WA-NT
      info="23 1 1 1 61 17 00"
      name="Soja T#1"
  />
  <WA-NT
      info="23 2 2 1 61 17 00"
      name="MatadorM"
  />
  <SCALE
      AdNr="0"
      Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0"
      Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
  />
  <SCALE
      AdNr="1"
      Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0"
      Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
  />
  <SCALE
      AdNr="2"
      Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0"
      Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
  />
  <GSM
      PIN=""
      PORT="0"
      TLF=""
  />
</NT3Config>
```

And this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NT3Config
><System
Dev="7"
PGMNR="24"
VCONF="800 800"
/><WA-NT
info="23 1 1 1 61 17 00"
name="Soja T#1"
/><WA-NT
info="23 2 2 1 61 17 00"
name="MatadorM"
/><SCALE
AdNr="0"
Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0"
Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
/><SCALE
AdNr="1"
Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0"
Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
/><SCALE
AdNr="2"
Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0"
Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
/><GSM
PIN=""
PORT="0"
TLF=""
/></NT3Config>
```

And this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NT3Config><System Dev="7" PGMNR="24" VCONF="800 800"/><WA-NT info="23 1 1 1 61 17 00" name="Soja T#1"/><WA-NT info="23 2 2 1 61 17 00" name="MatadorM"/><SCALE AdNr="0" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"/><SCALE AdNr="1" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"/><SCALE AdNr="2" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"/><GSM PIN="" PORT="0" TLF=""/></NT3Config>
```

And this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NT3Config>
  <System Dev="7" PGMNR="24" VCONF="800 800"/>
  <WA-NT info="23 1 1 1 61 17 00" name="Soja T#1"/>
  <WA-NT info="23 2 2 1 61 17 00" name="MatadorM"/>
  <SCALE AdNr="0" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"/>
  <SCALE AdNr="1" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"/>
  <SCALE AdNr="2" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0"/>
  <GSM PIN="" PORT="0" TLF=""/>
</NT3Config>
```

And you could even run into some of your unary tags as above being explicitly closed:

```
<System Dev="7" PGMNR="24" VCONF="800 800"/>
```

And:

```
<System Dev="7" PGMNR="24" VCONF="800 800"></System>
```

Are both saying the same thing, as far as XML is concerned.

PURELY because of the additional constraint of a locked down system, here's the really filthy way of doing it - but note the caveats above - we aren't parsing XML any more, we're doing plain text, and it can break really easily. (Brittle code makes your sysadmins sad).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/;
my ( $PGMNR ) = <DATA> =~ m/PGMNR=\"(\d+)\"/; 
print $PGMNR;

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NT3Config>
<System Dev="7" PGMNR="24" VCONF="800 800" /> 
<WA-NT name="Soja T#1" info="23 1 1 1 61 17 00" />
<WA-NT name="MatadorM" info="23 2 2 1 61 17 00" />
<SCALE AdNr="0" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" />
<SCALE AdNr="1" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" />
<SCALE AdNr="2" Setting="0 0 0 0 0 0 0" Calib="0 0 0 0 0 0" />
<GSM TLF="" PIN="" PORT="0" />
</NT3Config>
```

Or onelinering in perl:

```
perl -0777 -e 'print <> =~ m/PGMNR=\"(\d+)\"/;'
```

Comment: This i an industial Linux computer with very Little memory. Unfortunately I cannot install any programs on it. I have to use grep or awk.

Comment: @SørenBonefeld can you transfer the XML file to a computer that does (or can) have perl or xml parsing tools?